# JQuery Validation Weird Behavior on Validating Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm using jQuery validation to validate a dropdown list as follows:

here is the javascript part:

```
 $.ready(function(){ 
   $.validator.addMethod("dropdown", function (value, element) { return    validateDropDowns(this, value, element); });
    $('#form1').validate({
        onsubmit: false,
        focusInvalid: true,
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).toggleClass('invalid');
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").toggleClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).toggleClass('invalid');
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").toggleClass(errorClass);
        }
    });
});

function validateDropDowns(objContext, value, element) {
    return objContext.optional(element) || value != "-1";
}
```

and here is the markup part:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbGender" ClientIDMode="Static" meta:resourcekey="cmbGenderResource1">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1" Text="please select gender" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="male" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="female" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a submit button and on its click I validate the form `return $("#form1").valid();`

now everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE9 I get a very weird behavior; the dropdown works fine before validation and after validating it. when you try to open the dropdown it will close immediately.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I am seeing the same behavior in IE9.

Comment: there was a missing closing tag on the page HTML markup, once I fixed it everything works fine

Answer (score 3):

Add `onclick: false` in your validation option:

e.g.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onclick: false
})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue when calling addClass() on the element in the highlight function. I think your issue is to do with the toggleClass() function as well. Remove calls to toggleClass() and see if it still happens.